# How to create cross-service domain model mapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, microservices

I've two micro services in a Spring Boot micro service architecture. Let's say...

- HotSpot Service
- Attachment Service

Both services contains a domain model, of course in the end in separate JARs.

**HotSpot Domain Model (HotSpot Service)**

```
@Entity
public class HotSpot {

    @Id
    private Long id;
}
```

**Attachment Domain Model (Attachment Service)**

```
@Entity
public class Attachment {

    @Id
    private Long id;
}
```

If you create a new hot spot, it should be possible to add an additional attachment, like a describing image. So there should exist some kind of association/mapping between a hot spot entity and it's attachment. In a **monolithic** application, this would be implemented by annotating with JPA annotation `@OneToOne` or something like this.

How can I achieve this in a micro service architecture? Both classes are in separate JAR/projects! I thought about storing just the identifier as `Long` independently from JPA.
Any "better"/other ideas?

Comment: You could store the URI of the Attachement

Comment: As part of the entity class? What's the advantage about storing just the identifier?

Comment: A resource in REST has an URI. If you just store the id you have to configure the URI anywhere. But as @Didier mentioned it may not make sense to separate these two strongly related microservices. Microservices should be as independent as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would ask how are you dividing your micro services? It doesn't make sense to separate resources that are depending on each other. In your example I'm not sure if an Attachment can exists without a HotSpot. If it's not possible it definitively make no sense to have this two entities in two separate micro services.

Assumed your resources should be separated in two micro services, you need for each resource an URI. If resource A is related to resource B you could just store the URI of B in A, and if your mircroservices should be RESTful, provides a link in A to B with the right relation. Any automatic system like a OneToOne JPA relation doesn't exists.

Comment: Attachment can exists independently to hot spots, let's say as a user's profile image... Why would you recommend to store the URI instead of the identifier?

Comment: The URI is the identifier

Comment: Yea sure, I talked about the same like you... I was just talking about the type of data. But from point of view of the strategy it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

We have a semi-generic service (like the attachment service in your example) for Tagging.  You could use a similar structure to what we use, something like this:

```
// Contains types of "things" that can accept attachments
// Probably unnecessary if you aren't multi-tenant
public class EntityType
{
   public int Id;
   public Guid TenantId;
   public string Name;
}

// Contains a list of Entities available to Attach to
public class Entity
{
   public int Id;
   public int EntityTypeId;
   public string EntityId; // The unique Identifier for this Instance of Entity
}

// Contains actual attachment values (URI's) assigned to an Entity instance
public class EntityAttachment
{
   public int Id;
   public int EntityId;
   public string Attachment;
}
```

Even though the specific need is a little different, something like this might work well for you to build a generic `Attachments` service that lets you attach to almost anything but still keep the data well normalized and fast to query.

We build the `EntityType` and `Entity` datasets on the fly - if someone wants to add a tag to a type or ID we don't have, we add it silently.